# IIS 10 URLSegmentLength in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, config, iis-10

I am facing a problem that i have a url segment more that specified 260 chars like below:

> https://somedomain.com/xyz/SomeVeryLongSegment

I have the solution as well to set the DWORD value in the Registry for the same. Command line example below

> Set-ItemProperty -Path
> HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters -Name
> UrlSegmentMaxLength -Value 5000 -Type "Dword"

But what I do not want to do that since after doing that I will have to restart the http and w3svc. Since I have different applications hosted on the same server I do not want to restart them all.

I tried finding the solution if there is something similar which I can set in web.config per application. With that I already tried is setting maxUrl maxUrlLength maxQueryString maxQueryStringLength etc. etc in httpRuntime and requestLimit section of web.config.

Does anyone knows about the same?

Comment: Registry keys are used by Windows HTTP API (aka http and w3svc), so restarting the services (or simply rebooting the server) is your only option.

Comment: @LexLi yes but my question is if we can by pass the same and use only web.config to apply this property. I haven't found one. So, asking out if some one have any option for the same.

Comment: I already said what's your only option. Settings in `applicationHost.config` or `web.config` are never replacements of the registry keys, because IIS and Windows HTTP API are separate Windows components (isolated from each other).

Comment: That i already knew thanks @Le